# How to return null when I have " " in java?

Tags: java

I am coming for a help where I have a json object and return a string and few of my strings are return as `" "` meaning there is a empty value but there is a space in the quotation. So, what I want to accomplish is I need help to check or implement a way to show `null` value instead of `" "`. is there a way with my code below? thanks for the help.

Comment: Which field are you checking for " "?

Comment: I want to check all my fields from `step1 to step20` if possible. thanks!

Comment: `public string nullIfWhitespace(string s) { return s.trim().equals("") ? null : s }`

Comment: Using apache commons library, you could use `StringUtils.isBlank(String)` to check for blank values

Comment: Or simply `s.trim().equals("") ? null : s`

Comment: @RobertHarvey where can I call `nullIfWhitespace`? inside my switch statement?

Comment: The expression that does what you want is `s.trim().equals("") ? null : s`.  That will yield null if your string contains a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple method that trims the String (removes leading/trailing whitespace) and then checks if the `String` is empty should do the trick:

```
public String getTrimmedString(String str) {
    if (str.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return str.trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: where can I call getTrimmedString? inside my switch statement?

Comment: Thank you for your code. its working. I got it working. Also, can you please help me with my other question if you can. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56545577/how-to-show-one-instance-properly-in-java

Comment: I am not familiar with Jackson, myself.